# How to force msmq cleanup while on a fail over cluster setup

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, msmq

We have a cluster setup of an msmq service

When we need to cleanup some old messages, the space is not instantly released since msmq does this on an interval.

Is there a way to force this via a script or otherwise? All the resources I found on the internet spoke about local msmq operation instead of a clustered setup.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid a server restart since this is on production

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it being a clustered setup of MSMQ. A clustered queue manager is not really any different to a standalone one. You just need to run any clean-up request in the context of the clustered resource so you're talking to the clustered MSMQ queue manager. One way is to have a clustered command prompt which you can run your requests from.

[Forcing MSMQ to clean up its storage files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2008/12/19/forcing-msmq-to-clean-up-its-storage-files/)

Comment: how would someone open a "clustered command prompt"? first time I hear about this

Comment: Damn, times have changed :-( When I last used one several years ago, the OS still supported "Allow application to interact with desktop". Was thinking of https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2012/05/25/how-to-cluster-command-prompt-cmd-exe/

Comment: But you could cluster an application that automatically called the tidy function that didn't need to interact with desktop.